# UPDATE Using Self Join and Aggregates

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, self-join

I'm trying to update a table using a self join and aggregates.

For example, a table has the following columns:

> store, item, price, lowprice, lowprice store

I need to populate `lowprice` and `lowprice store`.

The `lowprice` would be:

```
Select item,min(price) group by item
```

The `lowprice store` would be the store with the `min(price)` for each item.

I'd love to be able to take it a step further as well. Say two stores offer an item at the same `lowprice`. Then the value for `lowprice store` would be 'store a/store b' but this part is less important.

I'm using SQL Server.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: This is a ***terrible terrible*** data structure.  When you have a price change, are you going to check every record in that table and update the lowprice for all occurrences of that item?  Same with the lowprice_Store, are you going to verify that after every insert/update/delete that gets run?  This is going to cause you so many headaches...

Comment: You would be better off putting this in a view instead of altering your underlying table for this info.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @JNK comment that you are better off using a `VIEW`. For SQL Server 2005+ you can try:

```
CREATE VIEW LowPrices 
AS

SELECT A.store, A.item, A.price, A.Low_Price, MIN(B.store) Low_Price_Store
FROM (  SELECT  *, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY item) Low_Price
    FROM YourTable) A
JOIN YourTable B
ON A.Low_Price = B.price
GROUP BY A.store, A.item, A.price, A.Low_Price
```

If you still want to do the `UPDATE`, then try:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT A.store, A.item, A.price, A.Low_Price, MIN(B.store) Low_Price_Store
    FROM (  SELECT  *, MIN(price) OVER(PARTITION BY item) Low_Price
            FROM YourTable) A
    JOIN YourTable B
    ON A.Low_Price = B.price
    GROUP BY A.store, A.item, A.price, A.Low_Price
)

UPDATE A
SET A.LowPrice = B.Low_Price,
    A.LowPriceStore = B.Low_Price_Store
FROM YourTable A
JOIN CTE B
ON A.store = B.Store AND A.item = B.item
```

Comment: `OVER ... PARTITION` is great, but often these hackish questions arise from developers stuck with out-dated systems who need to achieve the same semantics without the streamlined construct.